# Script to execute after submit Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

how to make Google Forms execute a script after submit instead of showing Confirmation message?

I tried setting a trigger from the **Script Editor** in the form which makes and shows a new html page:

```
function respondToFormSubmit(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}
```

and in **Edit** -> **Triggers for current project** I set it run on form submit but it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you can't.

> In Google Forms, custom user interfaces are only visible to an editor who opens the form to modify it, not to a user who opens the form to respond.

Source: HTML Service [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/#serve_html_as_a_google_docs_sheets_or_forms_user_interface)